# Sumatorio de algunas columnas dada cierta condición, con MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo que sumar en MySQL los valores de una tabla, pero no todos los valores, solo algunos.

Tengo que sumar los salarios por Departamentos pero solo si en alguno alguien gana más de 2500 ( con que uno lo gane se suman todos).

Así consigo la tabla de los SALARIOS, pero no los DEPARTAMENTOS:

```sql
select d.Nombre as 'Departamento',
sum(e.Salario) as 'Salario'
from empleados e, departamentos d
where (e.Departamento=d.Numero)
group by d.Numero;
```

Así consigo la tabla de los DEPARTAMENTOS pero no de los SALARIOS:

```sql
select d.Nombre as 'Departamentos',
sum(e.Salario) as 'Salario'
from departamentos d, empleados e
where (e.Salario>2500) and (e.Departamento=d.Numero)
group by e.Departamento;
```

Tengo que unirlo pero no sé cómo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un join, si quieres datos que no están en las dos tablas al mismo tiempo puedes hacer esto:

```
select d.Nombre as 'Departamentos',
sum(e.Salario) as 'Salario'
from departamentos d
LEFT OUTER JOIN empleados e ON (columna de la tabla departamento = columna de la tabla Salario) 
where (e.Salario>2500) and (e.Departamento=d.Numero)
group by e.Departamento;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias no conocia la instrucion LEFT OUTER JOIN, mil gracias

Comment: Los JOIN en general son súper útiles, te dejo unos enlaces para que los mires: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp